# The downloaded file with DownloadManager returns File.length() zero

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-download-manager, download-manager

I'm downloading an mp3 with `DownloadManager` and when the download is finished, on BroadcastReceiver I try to play it with MediaPlayer.

Why does `File.length()` for downloaded file return zero ? That prevents me from playing MP3 immediately after the download. After a few seconds the `File.length()` `returns true` as value and I can play the MP3!!

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(fileURL));
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(myExternalFile));
did = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

All permissions and other codes are correct, I am just not able to play mp3 immediately after the download.

Comment: when do you start playing your `MediaPlayer`? after what event?

Comment: @pskink when DownloadManager sends ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE on BroadcastReceiver

Comment: ok and what does `DownloadManager#query` shows in this `BroadcastReceiver#onReceive` ?

Comment: @pskink The downloded file status is DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL and after a few seconds i can play it!